# Read a text from managed bean and style it before displaying it in a pop-up

Tags: oracle-adf

I have to read a text from a managed bean, and then display the text in a pop-up. The pop-up gets displayed when a link is clicked. The requirement is to style the text, change the color and bold some portion of the text before displaying on the web page. I'm able to display the text with the   tags on the web page but the text is not getting bold. Please help me with the solutions to it. Thank you!

`<af:popup id="testPopup">`
     `<af:dialog id="d2" type="ok">
     <af:outputText value="TEST DESCRIPTION" id="ot2"/>
     <af:panelBox text="" id="pb5" showDisclosure="false">
        <af:outputFormatted value="#{pageFlowScope.TestBean.testMessage}"
        id="ot3" inlineStyle="width:300px;display:inline-block;word- 
        wrap:break-word"/>`
     `</af:panelBox>
     </af:dialog>
</af:popup>`

//Bean:
String testMessage = "<b>Lorem ipsum</b> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque r finibus consequat. Praesent egestas veneet euismod magna."

Comment: have you tried adding the bold <b> to the inline style instead of the string itself?

Comment: Hi Joe, I have not tried adding inline style, as we need to bold only some specific words in the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell us your exact jdev version, please.
If you run a .jspx page you should escape the '<' as ⁢
Try
   `<af:outputFormatted value="&lt;b>Bold&lt;/b> not bold" id="of1"/>`

Timo

Comment: Hi Timo,thank you, I have tried using  &lt;b> &lt;/b> tags this is working perfectly when this string is hard coded in the .jrxml page. This does not work when I'm reading the same text " &lt;b>Lorem ipsum&lt;/b> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque r finibus consequat. Praesent egestas veneet euismod magna." from the managed bean, it is displaying on the webpage as: <b>Lorem ipsum</b> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque r finibus consequat. Praesent egestas veneet euismod magna. The Jdeveloper version is: 11.1.1.9.0

Answer (score 0):

To have embedded html inside an outputText in ADF 11g you can set the **af:outputText** attribute  **escape="false**".

In your case, replace your ***af:outputFormatted*** by the following :

```
<af:popup id="testPopup"> 
   <af:dialog id="d2" type="ok">
     <af:outputText value="TEST DESCRIPTION" id="ot2"/>
     <af:panelBox text="" id="pb5" showDisclosure="false">
        <af:outputText value="#{pageFlowScope.TestBean.testMessage}" id="ot3" noWrap="true" escape="false"/>
     </af:panelBox>
   </af:dialog>
</af:popup>
```